# Both columns can't have nulls at the same time, only one per time, how to define this constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
create table tblFeedbacks
(
        Id int not null Primary key identity,
        ClientFeedback bit null,
        BarberFeedback bit null,
        BarberId int not null foreign key references tblBarberInfo(Id),
        ClientId int not null foreign key references tblClients(Id),
        Feedback nvarchar(max) not null
)
```

If clients feedback than 1 otherwise Barbers feedback 1, how to make a constraint for this situation?

- ClientFeedback bit null,
- BarberFeedback bit null,

Sorry for English

Comment: Or should I use a trigger for insert in this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `check` constraint.  For instance, if you want exactly one value to be `1`:

```
create table tblFeedbacks(
        Id int not null Primary key identity,
        ClientFeedback bit null,
        BarberFeedback bit null,
        BarberId int not null foreign key references tblBarberInfo(Id),
        ClientId int not null foreign key references tblClients(Id),
        Feedback nvarchar(max) not null),
        check ( (ClientFeedback = 1 and BarberFeedback = 0) or (ClientFeedback = 0 and BarberFeedback = 1) )
);
```

I am guessing that might be what you want.  But your question is specifically about `NULL` values.  That constraint would be:

```
        check ( ClientFeedback is not null or BarberFeedback is not null )
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with NULLs.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . I must've misread the question in a way suitable for the OP -- that only one of the columns should be `1`.  I updated the answer.

Comment: The constraint should be `check ( not (ClientFeedback is not null and BarberFeedback is not null ))`

Answer (score 1):

Use just one `FeedBackType` column, declared as `NOT NULL`, where you could set a value of `B` for Barber or `C` for Client (and possibly a `check` constraint limiting to those values as demonstrated in the other answer). Or, if you want to get fancy, have it be a foreign key back to a `FeedBackTypes` table.